# Using dynamic SQL to create a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

The following works:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = 
STUFF
    (
        (
        SELECT   ',' + QUOTENAME(b."NewName")
        FROM    (
                    SELECT  myKey, 
                        win = SUM(win)
                    FROM    xxx.dbo.yyy
                    GROUP BY myKey
                    ) x
                    INNER JOIN #NameSwitch b ON
                        x.myKey = b.myKey
        ORDER BY x.win DESC
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'');


SET @query =    
    'SELECT [Measure],' + @cols + ' 
    FROM  
        (
            SELECT  [NewName], [Measure], [Amount]
            FROM    #UnpivottedData x
        ) x
        PIVOT 
        (
            SUM(Amount)
            FOR [NewName] in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p ';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

But the problem is I'd like to input the results into a temporary table `#xxx` and then later on be able to use this data  via `SELECT * FROM #xxx`.

Do I need to `CREATE` #xxx using `dynamic sql` before running the above? If so can anyone point me in the direction of an example where this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are able to get the column names, so I'm assuming you can get to the column types. 
So you can do this (pesudo code)

```
CREATE TABLE #XXX (Measure <type>)
//
   generate scripts like 
SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE #XXX ADD '+ ColumnName+' '+ColumnTypeInfo
EXEC SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL
//

SET @query =    
    'INSERT INTO #XXX ([MEASURE], '+@cols+')
     SELECT [Measure],' + @cols + ' 
    FROM  
        (
            SELECT  [NewName], [Measure], [Amount]
            FROM    #UnpivottedData x
        ) x
        PIVOT 
        (
            SUM(Amount)
            FOR [NewName] in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p ';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

P.S.

1. I, myself, would choose `EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL` over `EXEC (@SQL)`, but in this case is just a matter of taste
2. I would simplify the code - you don't really need the `STUFF` part because you need your first comma in your concatenation, so there is no need to remove it. Also, you are forcing an XML column ( with the `TYPE` clause) only to convert it to `NVARCHAR`

**Later edit**

Disclaimer: this is not tested, as I didn't have your table structure and data

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @alter_query NVARCHAR(max);

SET @cols = 
        (
        SELECT   ',' + QUOTENAME(b."NewName")
        FROM    (
                    SELECT  myKey, 
                        win = SUM(win)
                    FROM    xxx.dbo.yyy
                    GROUP BY myKey
                    ) x
                    INNER JOIN #NameSwitch b ON
                        x.myKey = b.myKey
        ORDER BY x.win DESC
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) -- this will render smth like ",col1,col2" 
SET @alter_query = 
        (
        SELECT   ';ALTER TABLE #XXX ADD ' + QUOTENAME(b."NewName") +' '+ QUOTENAME(b."ColType") +' NULL'
        FROM    (
                    SELECT  myKey, 
                        win = SUM(win)
                    FROM    xxx.dbo.yyy
                    GROUP BY myKey
                    ) x
                    INNER JOIN #NameSwitch b ON
                        x.myKey = b.myKey
        ORDER BY x.win DESC
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) -- this will render smth like ";ALTER TABLE #XXX ADD col1 VARCHAR(MAX);ALTER ..." 

CREATE TABLE #XXX (Measure INT NULL)

EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @alter_query

SET @query =    
    'INSERT INTO #XXX (Measure+'@Cols+') SELECT [Measure]' + @cols + ' 
    FROM  
        (
            SELECT  [NewName], [Measure], [Amount]
            FROM    #UnpivottedData x
        ) x
        PIVOT 
        (
            SUM(Amount)
            FOR [NewName] in (' + STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, '') + ') -- here you need the STUFF to remove the first comma
        ) p ';


EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @Query

SELECT * from #XXX
```

Comment: +1 @Daniel thanks for the help and the extra tips; I think yours is probably more what I was looking for (although the use of `##` tables in the other answer is pretty nifty). Are you saying I can just drop 'STUFF' and it will still run? Have you got time to simplify my `SET @cols = ...` script and place the simplified version in your answer?

Comment: thanks for all the help/advice - it all seems to work ok - I think I need to read up about this `FOR XML PATH` as it seems pretty powerful

Answer (score 2):

try change including into clause

```
SET @query =    
'SELECT [Measure],' + @cols + ' 
 into ##xxx
FROM  
    (
        SELECT  [NewName], [Measure], [Amount]
        FROM    #UnpivottedData x
    ) x
    PIVOT 
    (
        SUM(Amount)
        FOR [NewName] in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p ';
```

this will create the temp table for the results...

if you realy want to create before the select..

you would need to gather the types of the columns to build the create table statment..

Comment: This way the `#xxx` temporary table won't be available after executing the dynamic sql, thus defeating the purpose of what op wants

Comment: yeah.. its true.. sorry, @Lamak.. hum.. would have to use a ##xxx to use this way

Comment: @Frederic - nice hack of the `##` - I'd not seen it used like this before

Comment: @whytheq , keep on mind that global temporary tables are visible for all connections.. and will persist there while exists an connection that references this table.. the table will be shared if you have two process, or more, that use this temporary table.. you may need to give different names for the ##xxx if need to isolate the process in some way... I am not sure.. but I guess will raise a error saying that the table already exists if you run this command simultaneously in two connections giving the same name for the ##xxxx

Answer (score 2):

Frederic is *almost* right -

Dynamic SQL is executed in a separate scope than the calling batch. Any temporary objects (tables, variables) declared within the dynamic SQL batch are only available within the dynamic SQL batch. You will be able to `SELECT INTO` a **global** temporary table - since those are connection specific and will persist across the dynamic SQL batch.

[sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: yeah I did a little mistake... I did change my answer for using global temporary table... ty...